# Reassign or refresh a singleton in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, singleton, provider

I have a Provider and in its register method I defined a singleton like this,

```
$this->app->singleton('my.custom.singleton', function ($app) {
    $config_value = $app->make($this->config('key'));
    return new MyClass($config_value);
});
```

as you see, I get a config value and put it as a parameter in my class.

In another place of my project, I change the value of `config('key')` using code:

`Config:set('key',$my_changed_value);`

and I call a method of `MyClass` that uses the parameter that I send it to the class in my provider above.

But `MyClass` not use the new value of `config('key')`. I think it happens because the singleton has been defined with the default value of config.

I think it will be ok if I could redefine the singleton after assigning new values of config.

Or is there any solution for my issue? Am I wrong? What can I do to use the new value in `MyClass`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just assign `null` to it and it will be created from scratch on the next call

```
app()->instance(PaymentServiceContract::class, null);
```

Answer (score -2):

It might be related config cache, Do you use config cache ?

Can you try again after clear cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: I did this before, It's not answer